# Changing address location for a new build in trace32

Tags: powerpc, trace32, lauterbach

We are using python scripts to run tests in trace32. There was a recent change in the build with few features going for a change.

Is there a way we could determine the new address locations for breakpoints without rewriting the scripts again? (At least for the features which did not have change)

Comment: Hello @boon, your question is lacking information: How do you determine where you want to set the breakpoints? I guess you want to set breakpoints on symbols?

Comment: Yes, we place breakpoints on symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Query the symbols address and then set the breakpoint, e.g. using

```
sYmbol.BEGIN(<symbol>)
sYmbol.RANGE(<symbol>)
```

and then set the breakpoint on the resulting address, e.g.

```
Break.Set sYmbol.BEGIN(<symbol>)
Break.Set sYmbol.RANGE(<symbol>)
```